# Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine on linux system

Tags: command-line, gnome, java, openjdk, macosx

I am trying to use bbmap (`pileup.sh in= my.fa out=new.txt`) to check the sequencing depth of assembly scaffolds derived from illumina reads.

Using Linux, I installed java jdk as you see:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

Also, I installed **bbmap** module.

When I tried to run the pipeline : `pileup.sh in= my.fa out=new.txt`, I got this error :

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to allocate 207104KB bitmaps for parallel garbage collection for the requested 6627328KB heap.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please start with OS/release details (they provide a huge clue as to your software stack). This is not a generic GNU/Linux support site.